# Can you remove a child from its parent before its SKAction sequence is completed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am coding a Bullet Hell type game for IOS, and in this game, there are different types of enemies that travel down the screen. To perform this movement, an SKAction sequence is used when the child (or clone) creation function is called. The first action involves moving the enemy (an SKSpriteNode) to the the bottom of the screen, and the second removes the child from the parent, effectively deleting it.

```
let action = SKAction.moveToY(-enemyT1.size.height, duration: 3.0);
let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent();
enemyT1.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]));
self.addChild(enemyT1);
```

However, there is a situation in which the child must be deleted before reaching the end of the screen, and I was wondering if you can remove the child in a different conditional code block without the initial remove causing an error (or vice versa).

```
if(enemyT1Healths[indexOfEnemy!] <= 0){
    enemyT1.removeFromParent();
    enemyT1Sprites.removeAtIndex(indexOfEnemy!);
    enemyT1HealthBars[indexOfEnemy!].removeFromParent();
    enemyT1HealthBars.removeAtIndex(indexOfEnemy!);
    enemyT1Healths.removeAtIndex(indexOfEnemy!);
}
```

Comment: What errors you are actually talk about ?

Comment: The title sounds like a legal question about guardianship :D

Comment: @Honey the answer would be "Only with SKChildProtectiveServices

Comment: I think you are going about this wrong. IMO, it would be best to not remove something via an action.. Set a flag or some sort so that way the next step in the SK game loop can parse the flags, then determine what to do. Example, in `didEvaluateActions` you can check flags to see whether or not you need to remove the enemy, which would have no conflicts because you will simply remove the action from the sequence when you remove the node.

Comment: now that I'm thinking about it, the way you are doing shouldn't cause issues either, unless there are physics involved...